# O que é Headless Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando um programa para comparar preços em NodeJS, e nas minhas pesquisas me deparei com este termo, o que seria Headless Browser e como ele funciona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Headless Browser** (Tradução directa - Navegadores sem cabeça)

**Headless Browser** isso significa apenas que não há interface gráfica do usuário (GUI). Ou seja, é um navegador da web sem uma interface gráfica do usuário controlada programaticamente, ele é geralmente usado para automação, teste e outros propósitos.

Ora vejamos; O servidor retorna arquivos ou scripts [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript) injetados em uma resposta [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Gloss%C3%A1rio/HTML) e o navegador os processa. Agora, isso é um problema se estivermos fazendo algum tipo automação da Web, porque, mais do que nunca, o conteúdo que gostaríamos de ver é realmente renderizado pelo código JavaScript e não pode ser acessado a partir da resposta HTML não processada que o servidor entrega.

Agora, e se pudéssemos aproveitar essa funcionalidade para nossas necessidades e ter uma maneira de controlar os navegadores programaticamente? É exatamente aí que entra a automação do ***Headless Browser***!

[Uma lista de (quase) todos os Headless Browser existentes.](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)